# Question about edge disjoint path

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I'm studying about edge disjoint path.

If there is $3$ distinct vertices $(u,v,w)$ in given Graph $G = (V,E)$,

Let there is $u \to v$ has $k$ $(k>1)$ edge disjoint paths, and $v \to w$ has $k$ edge disjoint paths, then can we say that $u \to w$ has $k$ edge disjoint paths?

In my opinion, if there is $u \to v$ edge disjoint paths has a one path which is $w$ is internal node of that path, then we cannot sure that argument.

Is there any suggestion or disagreement about my opinion?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- If you can use network flows, then set all the edge capacities to $1$ and observe that you have two flows of size at least $k$ from $u$ to $v$ and from $v$ to $w$. Can you say anything about a flow from $u$ to $w$?
- Another approach is via [Menger theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem), that is, by removing $(k-1)$ edges from the graph you can destroy at most $(k-1)$ paths from $u$ to $v$ and at most $(k-1)$ paths from $v$ to $w$. Hence, there is still at least one path from $u$ to $w$. In other words, $u$ and $w$ are at least $k$-edge connected.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: If I understand correctly, then we have $k$ edge-disjoint paths from $u$ to $v$, lets call them $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$, and $k$ edge-disjoint paths from $v$ to $w$, lets call them $Q_1,Q_2,\ldots,Q_k$.  And we want to prove the existence of $k$ edge-disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$.  The tricky part is that $P_i$ and $Q_j$ may not be edge-disjoint.

Comment: Thanks to Rebecca, I want to ask about it.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones That makes much more sense (I understood $k$-edge disjoint path instead of $k$ edge disjoint path_s_).

Comment: @dtldarek It is k edge disjoint paths not k-edge disjoint path.

Comment: @Tony_SSU Thanks to Rebecca I know that already and I have updated my post ;-)